# Returning a variable from nested for loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I am writing a lottery class, and the rest of my code is working except for the method which compares the amount of matching lottery numbers.  I can't figure out for the life of me how to keep a count of the matches AND return it.

I'm fairly new to java so I apologize if this is a blatantly obvious answer.

Here is the code for the method I am working with:

```
public int numIntsInCommon(int[] picks){
     int inCommon = 0;

     for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
     {
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
           if (lotteryNumbers[counter] == picks[index])
              inCommon += 1;

        }
        return inCommon;
     }

     return inCommon;
  }
```

Right now it currently only returns 0.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you intend to have the inner return statement?  That could be cutting your execution short and returning a value earlier than you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `return inCommon` from the for loop.  The outer return is never being reached.

Answer (score 2):

The first `return` statement will return the `inCommon` value before the method has had chance to complete the outer loop. I'm not sure the point of that first return statement at all, really.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int numIntsInCommon(int[] picks)
{
     int inCommon = 0;

     for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
     {
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
           if (lotteryNumbers[counter] == picks[index])
              inCommon++;
        }
     }

     return inCommon;
}
```

Should be fine now. What you have done before, was jump out of the nested loops after first iteration. In other words: thanks to your nested return, the loop ended after counter = 1.

Comment: what `index`? There isn't any `index` in place, where `user...` placed first `return`. Only `counter` variable

Comment: Oh yea, I've forgoten where the first return was. It wasn't in the nested loop, it was outside of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In java, "return" means termination of a function, so if your return in inner loop, the outer loop will never be executed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java Collections Framework and define your lotteryNumbers and picks as List then your problem is much easier to solve, something like this:

```
public int numIntsInCommon(List<Integer> picks) {
    List<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>(picks);
    matches.retainAll(lotteryNumbers);
    return matches.size();
}
```